# Just updated from 16.04 to 18.04, booting problem

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade, updates

When I try going into unity/Ubuntu it only shows a black screen and the mouse courser which I can move but I can't do anything else except switching the screen back to chrome OS. Plz could somebody help me out.

Comment: the best option would be to do a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04, because Ubuntu 18.04 uses Gnome as DE and Ubuntu 16.04 uses Unity

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: first backup all your data and follow one of this: 1.https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu/  2. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview 3. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: No I can't use anything in the desktop environment

Comment: you can use Ubuntu 18.04 Live to copy your files, if you have something important and then proceed with the installation

Comment: so how do I delete it and reinstall it and make sure i download version 18.04?

Comment: if you have only ubuntu 16.04 installed, boot with Ubuntu 18.04 Live, backup your files and proceed with the installation, where the installation process will delete any previous OS..